# How can I change link color in html email?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I tried a few ways to change the link's color, but it didn't work. These what I tried:

None of them works and the link's color is still blue.
How can I overwrite the blue color to my own color?

```html
<span style="text-decoration: none; color: #959595">www.xyz.com</span>
<span style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #959595 !important">www.xyz.com</span>
<font style="text-decoration: none; color: #959595">www.xyz.com</font>
```

Comment: You do not have links. You have spans. They are all Grey

Comment: Also `font` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **mplungjan** I realised that my solutions were wrong and it's an easy fix.
Thank you for everyone who posted solutions!

```
<a href="www.xyz.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #959595; cursor: pointer">www.xyz.com</a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the link to be clickable?

use anchor <a> tag, then style it

```html
<a href="www.xyz.com">www.xyz.com</a>


<style>
a:link {
    color: green;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}

a:active {
    color: purple;
}
</style>
```